# Kubernetes control plane how to increase Endpoint Slices for Service

Tags: kubernetes, kube-controller-manager

I am gettingthe below error and unable to resolve this.
***"Error updating Endpoint Slices for Service default/centosdei2-service: failed to update centosdei2-service-dc4tm EndpointSlice for Service default/centosdei2-service: EndpointSlice.discovery.k8s.io "centosdei2-service-dc4tm" is invalid: ports: Too many: 109: must have at most 100 items"***

Tried to add "    - --max-endpoints-per-slice=150" in the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml and restarted the master but didnt work. Any pointers?

Comment: How many master node you have? Did you do it in all of those?

Comment: i have one master and 1 worker node in the cluser.

Comment: Can you simply instead of editing mafifest execute command: $ kube-controller-manager  --max-endpoints-per-slice=150

Comment: There is no such command "kube-controller-manager" . Throwed error that "bash: kube-controller-manager: command not found...". it need the config file change and update

Comment: Please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481043/kubernetes-controller-manager-pod-not-updating ?

Comment: @Malgorzata the solution didn't work. Thanks for the pointer. thi step is getting the new parameters but notreflecting at the time of service deployment.

Comment: Did you manage to solve problem thanks to my pointer?

Comment: @Malgorzata, i used that method to restart the container and able to see that the parameter is taken by the new container but still it didn't work. Someone from that thread also got the same issue.

Comment: Did you manage to find workaround ?